# How to read txt files and convert into data frame using Apache Beam Python?

Tags: python, etl, apache-beam, transformation

My txt file contains stock market data without any delimiter. So I have to transform that into structured columns and convert it into a data frame using the Apache beam python pipeline. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You will need a delimiter to parse a file. If you don't have one, then how you are going to know the basic structure of the data (columns, rows, types). If you don't have a traditional delimitation ( , ) you can use other options for it such as fixed length, tab separation, ( | ) or get the data in a supported format so your parse will understand the input file.

Comment: Also, in case you didn't notice, Beam offers a DataFrame API: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/dsls/dataframes/overview/

Answer (score 0):

I have a made brief compilation on how to use beam.dataframe ingesting data with apache beam. Below you can see some of the functions that [beams dataframe supports](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.25.0/apache_beam.dataframe.io.html) , as you can see those functions are similar to the one used on pandas. Its because apache beam have a implemented a function `_ReadFromPandas` which make use of pandas library to get data from your sources into a beam dataframe.

**apache_beam.dataframe.io**

- **read_csv** : Emulates [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) from Pandas, but as a Beam PTransform. Use this to get a deferred Beam dataframe representing the contents of the file. `csv` -> stands for comma-separated values.

```
df = p | beam.dataframe.io.read_csv(…)
```

- **read_fwf**: Emulates pandas [read_fwf](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html). *fwf stands for Fixed Width Text File. You can find more detailed information on this [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/parsing-fixed-width-text-files-with-pandas-f1db8f737276).

```
data = "mydata.txt"  # content --> "MyFixedText12345"
read_fwf(data, colspecs=[(0, 10), (10, None)], header=None)
# expected dataframe = [[MyFixedText, 12345]]
```

- **read_json**: Emulates pandas [read_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html). Parse json data structure file to create the dataframe.

```
#json structure
{"row 1":{"col 1":"a","col 2":"b"},"row 2":{"col 1":"c","col 2":"d"}}
```

- **read_html**: Emulates pandas [read_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html). Will parse HTML tables into list of dataframes.

As mention in the comments you will have to define the structure of your data, so it will be able to fit into one of options apache_beam have for dataframes. As beam makes use of pandas, you can find more detailed information about pandas [io tools](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html), keep in mind that according to official [beam documentation](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.25.0/apache_beam.dataframe.io.html) not all pandas dataframe options are supported by beams.

For more info about beam dataframes, check this [link](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/dsls/dataframes/overview/)

Comment: Hello Kartikey Garg, did you manage to get it work?